# Copy & Paste Only Cells With Data While Keeping Row Spacing

Tags: excel, formula

I've highlighted a column & I can select only the cells with text by using Go To & selecting constants. I'm trying to paste into an existing column in within the same row, but when I paste, it gets pasted without all the spacing.

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
First Name  Last Name     
First Name  Mid Init    Last Name
First Name  Last Name   
First Name  Mid Init    Last Name        
First Name  Mid Init    Last Name
```

the above gets pasted into:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
First Name  Last Name
First Name  Mid Init    Last Name
First Name  Mid Init    Last Name
First Name  Mid Init    Last Name
```

I'm only trying to replace the middle initials with the last name so there's only first & last names left. I'm not too familiar with VBA, but those are the only answers I've found. Is there a formula or another tool to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. Use `ISBLANK` on column `C` to check if you have a `Last Name` in that column or column `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula for first name in A1 of the output sheet:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Then for the last name in B1 of the output sheet:

```
=IF(Sheet1!C1<>"",Sheet1!C1,Sheet1!B1)
```

Then copy/drag down.

[image]

Comment: Great! That worked perfectly. Is the logical test just testing if there is any content in the cell by saying less than or greater than?

Comment: `<>` means does not equal.  @IsaiahO please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.